# Constructive Induction

Tags: combinatorics, induction

An airplane crashes on an island in the middle of nowhere. The $n$, ($n \geq 1$) passengers all end up apart from everyone else. We call each passenger a group. The passengers start wandering around. As each group meets another group everyone from one group shakes hands with everyone from the other group, and then they form a new larger group. Eventually everyone meets and they form one large group of size $n$.

Assume the formula for the the handshakes is $an^2 + bn + c$.

So I know the base case is $n = 2$ cause one person can't have a handshake
That would be $a^4 + 2b + c$.

For the inductive hypothesis, do I assume for $n \geq 2$?

Comment: In the end, everyone has shaken hands with everyone else, once each. No reason to be distracted by different group sizes meeting up in different orders. And the base case can still be $n=1$, with zero hand shakes, there is no issue there.

Answer (score 2):

To continue withe the direction Arthur mentioned, see that the total number of handshakes will be $$f(n) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

This is by a combinatorial argument rather than an induction proof. See that everyone ultimately will shake hands with everyone else. So there are $n$ choices for the first person involved with the handshake, and $n-1$ people for the other. Doing this, we over count by a factor of $2$ so we must divide by this factor to get the desired result.

But if you would also like an induction argument for why this formula works, continue reading:

Plugging in $n=1$ into $f(n)$ does result in $0$ handshakes, as it should.

You can then assume it's true for $k\ge 1$ and the goal is to show that it is true for $k+1$.

The number of handshakes of $k+1$ people can be looked at as the number of handshakes that involve the $(k+1)$th person and the number of them that don't.

There will be $k$ other people this person needs to handshake with, and there are the other $f(k)$ handshakes that did not involve them so we have $$k + f(k) = k + \frac{k(k-1)}{2} = \frac{2k + k^2 - k}{2} = \frac{(k+1)(k)}{2} = f(k+1) $$

as desired.